# Go: cannot package in symlink

Tags: git, go, symlink, git-submodules

I have one go project. In this project, for example I have a `lib_project` that is a symlink to another directory, for example: `github_project`

After I pull source code to local, I update another git submodules (`github_project` is one submodule). And then I go here and compile project.

After that, I go to my main project and try to run command go. I meet exception:

```
package github.com/main_project/test.go: cannot find package "github.com/main_project/lib_project/some_random_file.go" in any of:

        /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.7.1/libexec/src/github.com/main_project/lib_project/some_random_file.go (from $GOROOT)

        /Users/my_user/Documents/go/src/github.com/main_project/lib_project/some_random_file.go (from $GOPATH)
```

I have tested and see that the directory `github.com/main_project/lib_project/some_random_file.go` is exsit. I can cd to this and open file. That looks like Go doesn't recognize symlink folder (in this case is `lib_project`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Go tools purposely don't follow symlinks. Make sure there aren't any in your GOPATH, and always use the full import path relative to `$GOPATH/src/` for installed packages, and relative to the `vendor/` directory for vendored packages.

Comment: FWIW you *can* symlink local packages from within vendor sub-directories. I use this extensively to [in-git-repo development](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/tree/go/Makefile) build-tree test the [libcap/cap](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/cap) and [libcap/psx](https://pkg.go.dev/kernel.org/pub/linux/libs/security/libcap/psx) packages.